# union multiple spark dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have about 10,000 different Spark Dataframes that needs to be merged using `union`, but the `union` takes a very long time.

Below is a brief sample of the code I ran, dfs is a collection of the Dataframes that I'd like to use `union` on:

```py
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

dfOut = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
```

It seems that when I union 100-200 dataframes, it is quite fast. But the running time increases exponentially when I increase the number of dataframes to merge.

Any suggestions on improving the efficiency? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure about `union` but I've experienced issues with long sequences of other transformations (usually dozens of sequential `withColumn` transformation). The solution for my case was to insert `cache` calls between each N transformations. And the reason was garbage collection on driver node: as number of transformations grows larger, it takes more memory (maybe exponentially more) to build and optimize the execution plan. You may try to split `dfs` into chunks of 100-200 dataframes, union everything in chunk, then call `cache` or `checkpoint` then union all chunks. I hope, it will help.

Answer (score 2):

The detail of this issue is available at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12616.

> Union logical plan is a binary node. However, a typical use case for
>   union is to union a very large number of input sources (DataFrames,
>   RDDs, or files). It is not uncommon to union hundreds of thousands of
>   files. In this case, our optimizer can become very slow due to the
>   large number of logical unions. We should change the Union logical
>   plan to support an arbitrary number of children, and add a single rule
>   in the optimizer (or analyzer?) to collapse all adjacent Unions into
>   one.
>
> Note that this problem doesn't exist in the physical plan, because the
>   physical Union already supports an arbitrary number of children.

This was fixed in version 2.0.0. If you have to use a version lower than 2.0.0, union the data using RDDs union function.

Comment: Thanks for the information! What are the modifications I could take to optimize the performance in this case? I'm using spark 2.4